Python Error : [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'
For some reason with what I am trying I cannot get to find the excel Sheet1.  Here is my code:
filename = 'ALC_2022068_06282024-testing copy.xlsx'




sql = r"""INSERT INTO tblALC_test ([dateofnotice], [provnbr])
          SELECT e.[dateofnotice], e.[provnbr]
          FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database={xl}].[Sheet1$] AS e;
       """.format(xl=filename)


conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' +
                  r'DBQ=F:\Kevin\CPD_Night\ALC_Testing.accdb;')    
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.commit()

cursor.close()
conn.close()

The code seems to find the MS Access DB and found the MS Excel file but could not find the tab : Sheet1.
Is this a syntax or some other feature I should add to the line(s)?
